# Older version of php with Xampp

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, version, bluehost

I installed Xampp currently on version 1.8.2 and comes with php version 5.4.16.

My server off of bluehost is currently on php version 5.2.17.

Is there a way to install the older version of php (5.2.17) on my Xampp so my local is compatible with my server?

Or...

Would I have to download an older version of Xampp (one that supports php 5.2.17 version)?

and if that is the case...

How would I know which Xampp version comes with php 5.2.17

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thank you,
Baraa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it turns out there is not an Xampp version that supports the exact php 5.2.17 version.

So I installed Xampp version 1.7.1 which supports php version 5.2.8.

And that made my local compatible with the php off of my server!